# On the Regularity of Measures

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is a regular measure in the sense that

1) $\mu(K)<\infty$ for any compact set $K$.

2) $\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(G): G\supseteq E~\text{open}\}$.

3) $\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K): ~\text{compact}~K\subseteq E\}$.

Now for any nonnegative locally integrable Borel measurable $\omega$, define 
\begin{align*}
\nu(E)=\int_{E}\omega d\mu,~~~~E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}),
\end{align*}
does it follow that $\nu$ being regular?

I can do this when $\omega$ is continuous, by using a theorem of Choquet. But in general the merely assumption that $\omega$ being Borel measurable, I have no idea.

Any help?

Remark:

The theorem of Choquet says, if the following conditions are met, then the set function $\nu$ is regular.

i) $\nu(\emptyset)=0$.

ii) $E_{2}\subseteq E_{2}$ implies $\nu(E_{1})\leq\nu(E_{2})$.

iii) If $K_{i}$ is a decreasing sequence of compact sets, then $\nu(\bigcap_{i}K_{i})=\lim_{i}\nu(K_{i})$.

iv) If $E_{i}$ is an increasing sequence of arbitrary sets, then $\nu(\bigcup_{i}E_{i})=\lim_{i}\nu(E_{i})$.

Comment: Every locally finite Borel measure on a second countable locally compact Hausdorff space is regular, so you are good.

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find the proof of that statement?

Comment: It's for instance in Rudin's "Real and complex analysis", Theorem 2.18. The exact assumption is that every open set should be sigma compact. But this is implied by the assumptions instated above.